# Dual Monitor keeps disconnecting

Tags: display

I have 2 of the same monitors which I'm trying to connect . When I have both of them connected at the same time one monitor goes black for a second and then comes back , but then the second monitor goes black and comes back and that just keeps repeating.

Some details

Both monitors are connected with VGA , one is connected by a DVI adapter and the other one by an HDMI converter to the computer.

When starting windows both work perfectly at the same time.

When one of the monitors disconnects I'm hearing the Windows disconnect sound.

The graphics card is AMD radeon HD 7800.

The monitors are Hannsg HP222DJ